# Creating Directories to categorize the images based on its type in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I have to create a multiple directory like this path("images/wallpaper/flower"). It should be stored in the External Memory of the phone.

How to do it? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the SDcard path using [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) and then create the dir structure with the Java's File class.

You should know that the sdcard can be unmounted so check it's status first.

Comment: Thanks. i can create the directories. But how to create a image file inside that directory?

Comment: You are asking how to get images from internet and saving them on the sdcard?